# Fantasy Grounds - Adding different attacks with one weapon

Tags: pathfinder-2e, fantasy-grounds

In the Fantasy grounds software: I am playing a ranger in PF2e and I am trying to understand how to apply my Hunter's Edge: Flurry ability to weapons I own. I've imported a weapon into my inventory and it shows up in my action's tab no problem. However since I'm looking to use this edge ability it doesn't necessarily apply to all foes that I am fighting equally.
So how do I apply two weapon-actions with different bonuses under my actions tab? and most importantly how do I link BOTH to the associated weapon without doing something silly like adding a "fake" weapon in my inventory?

You can see in the image that I've figured out how to add a second action, but it is not actively linked to the appropriate weapon.
[image]

Alternately, is there just some toggle I can switch on and off to apply modifiers on the fly?

Comment: I myself don't use Fantasy Grounds, but if I recall correctly there is a large user base on the Pathfinder 2e Reddit. If you don't get an answer here, it might be worth checking there.

Comment: @ESCE Already gave that a try; You get a lot of conflicting answers on Reddit, including users using slightly different software, versions, or with mods. It's why I prefer Stackexchange as we try to cultivate a more factual community using default baselines. But I do appreciate the helpful directions.

Comment: I don't use fantasy grounds either, but have you checked the Pathfinder discord (the one associated with the main PF reddit, not the meh PF 2e that spontaneously came into existence). Typically they've got knowledgeable people, and given the size of the userbase, you're probably more likely to find ones that work.

Comment: Are you using Fantasy Grounds Unity or Classic? (not sure if it makes a difference for the answer, I've only used Unity)

Comment: @PixelMaster Fantasy Grounds Unity version as well.

Comment: Did you find out the answer?  If so, what?

Comment: @A. B. Nope, no answer yet. I am aware that fantasy grounds has several features that are on the planned to-do list, but have been unable to find if this is one of them, or if it already exists, or no plans.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is that you can't have everything that you want.  That's the bad news.  The good news is that making two weapon lines is not the best way to handle your problem, so you can get a usable solution by taking a better approach.*

Attacking your prey while flurrying is not, after all, an attack with a different weapon.  It is attacking your prey.  That sort of thing is resolved in Fantasy Grounds with a pair of effects:  one to set a creature as your prey and the other to improve your MAP when attacking your prey.

[image: Screenshot of Fantasy Grounds with a Ranger that implements a Hunt prey focus spell]

This image contains pretty much everything you need to do to make it work.  It and the instructions below are based on [this FG update post](https://www.fantasygrounds.com/forums/showthread.php?57774-PFRPG2-ruleset-Release-16-now-in-quot-live-!&p=508118&viewfull=1#post508118).

We start by giving our ranger a new focus spell class (right click Actions window, `Add Focus Spell Class`).  Call it "Ranger abilities".  Yes, I know this is not a spell, but it's a limitation of FG that it doesn't yet know about abilities that are neither attacks nor spells.  So we call all abilities spells.

We add a focus spell, "Hunt prey" (right-click `Focus Spells`, `Add Spell`).  We add two effect lines (right-click `Hunt prey`, `Add Spell Action`, `Add Effect` to add an effect line).  The first effect we call `TR's Prey`; it will be applied to a creature when Test Ranger marks it as their prey.  The second effect we call `Flurry Hunter's Edge; IFT:CUSTOM(TR's Prey); MAP:-3`.  It will be applied to Test Ranger at all times.

In the image, these abilities are highlighted in pink.

What the Flurry Hunter's Edge effect does is check each creature you attack for the TR's Prey effect.  If the target of your attack has that effect, it changes your multi-attack penalty to 0/-3/-6.  The [agile] trait is accounted for automatically.

Note that the name of the effect applied to your prey (`TR's Prey` in this example) has to match the effect checked in the hunt prey effect exactly.

It is important to note that using the `MAP` effect is incompatible with the second and third attack listed on the weapon line.  If you use those, FG assumes you are overriding its MAP calculations.  Instead you have to declare yourself to be making your second and third attacks by toggling on the `MA#2` or `MA#3+` buttons respectively.  They are on the combat tracker and highlighted in blue in the image.

*:  There are hacks with throwing dogslicers and the like that can also apply, but those quickly get ridiculous.

Comment: What's this about throwing dogslicers?

Comment: You can technically copy a melee weapon, assign it a range, add it to your inventory, change the automatically added ranged attack to a melee attack, and then edit the item to remove the range to get one weapon associated with two melee attacks.

I did mention that this was both a hack and ridiculous.